# Ashamed of my own answer. Should I delete it?

Tags: support, answers, late-answers

I have been on physics stack exchange for about four years. Some of my answers I am proud of some of them not so much. There is one particular answer where I did my best at the time but I lacked the knowledge to understand what OP was asking. Some people however liked the answer and nobody else replied. I'd like to write a new answer. Should I delete the old one? Should I edit it?

In the future I definitely shouldn't answer something I don't understand. I remember wanting to ask in a comment but not having enough rep at the time.

[If you are curious here is the old answer.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/328108/74376)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to write an *entirely new answer*, i.e. the new answer has little to nothing in common with the old, then you should post it as a new answer, not as an edit of your old answer.

Since your old answer is not accepted, you are free to delete it at any time. However, given that it has a net positive score, apparently some people found it useful regardless of what you think of the answer today. If the answer is *wrong* you should definitely delete - or even better, correct - it, but otherwise there doesn't really seem to be a pressing need to delete it.